# audio tag does not work properly in chrome

Tags: html, audio, tags, mp3

I use the audio tag in a table. it has the format like following:

```
    <table style=";width:100%;" cellspacing="5">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1.</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
    <td>
          <audio controls="controls" preload="none">
        <source src="/v/vspfiles/music/294/track_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              <embed height="50" width="100" src="/v/vspfiles/music/294/track_01.mp3">
        Your browser does not support this audio format.</audio>
        </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

But this does not work successfully in Chrome every time. 
For example:
The audio on: https://www.cityluxe.sg/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=294 will not played on Chrome at all. But the text "Your browser does not support this audio format." is not displayed as well. However it works well with other browsers (ie,ff,safari). The browsers are all updated to the latest version.

I thought it might not work well in table. But there are successful case like this one:
https://www.cityluxe.sg/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=306.
All the audio files can be played in all the browsers (ie,ff,safari,chrome) perfectly.

I do not know what is the problem, is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640450/audio-tag-for-mp3-doesnt-really-work-on-chrome/41911882#41911882

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution.
MP3 with 192kbps doesn't work.

MP3 with 128 works fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave this as a comment but it won't let me (I have no reputation :( )

http://www.jplayer.org/HTML5.Audio.Support/

> **Chrome 4**: Has enabled File seeking, which appears to have degraded the
>   performance. Seeking to a new “start download point” in the file is
>   enabled. (This seems to cause more problems than it solves and is
>   especially noticable with larger file sizes, where changing the play
>   position ahead of the downloaded point causes the sound to stop/start
>   as the download is restarted from the new position.)